# What is the prognosis for Camellia japonica with 90% of leaves removed?

Tags: pest-damage

The damndeer ate 90 % of the leaves and 75 % of the leaf buds ( 1/4 to 1/2 inch long at this time) from a 4 ft tall *Camellia japonica*. It has been in that location about 4 years. Normally there is a fence around it but I forgot to replace it recently and the damndeer got the plant. I expect it will live but wonder how badly it has been hurt.

Comment: You need to rein the deer in. What season is it, and where's the nearly obligatory picture?

Comment: The question should be ; Are there very small leaf buds that will start growing now. Because of my limited abilities , I need a grandchild to put the photo here; it is in my phone now.

Comment: @blacksmith37 If you talk to the grandchild, have him or her install the app on your phone and show you how to upload photos *directly from the phone*. And rest assured that there is a menu that will guide you through the steps every time.